# Import an Oracle dump file using a second server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I want to import a dump file into an Oracle server, `SRV1`.

Due to space constraints on `SRV1`, I cannot copy the dump to the server and then import it.

I copied the dump to another Oracle server, `SRV2` and tried to execute the `impdp` command using the `tables` option.

So I am trying to import from a different server.  I am getting the following errors.

What should I do?

Comment: which error message do you get? was the export created with `exp` or with `expdp`? What is the version of the database from where the data were exported? which tool you use to import? wich operating system do you run on TGTSVR?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. The dump file must always be accessible from within the filesystem of the target server (the one where you import).

What you could do, is to setup up a DBLink between the two servers. Then you can do a DataPump directly from one server to the other (using the `network_link` option) without the need of a file at all.

See [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#i1007380) for details
And [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump#Network_import) for an example